Raster map tile server service and configuration
My question is very similar to AWS configuration for running low-to-medium bandwidth Web map app, but I am seeking current advice since it is from 12 years ago.
I'm interested in what services and configurations the community uses to serve slippy raster tiles. Both cost and performance are considerations. Of course, I'd like the tiles served as fast as possible to the consumer while being cost-effective.
I'm starting with a special prototype area of 1 million 512x512 tiles at zoom level 18. Eventually, I plan to serve roughly 2.8 billion tiles of the USA at Zoom level 18. My first area is about 30GB.
This Reddit post comparing AWS S3 costs with CloudFront is interesting. Apparently, CloudFront is more expensive and more distributed.
I guess a nice thing about AWS is that I can scale up to more processors and use load balancing as needed.
What service configuration are you using to host raster tiles?
I seek an idea of how many monthly users, simultaneous users and cost.
